# ISO 8601 date into MySQL database - just can't get it to work

Tags: mysql, datetime, iso8601

I've got a really simple problem but I just can't sort it, fairly new to PHP and MySQL which is why im struggling

Overview - I want to insert an ISO8601 date into MySQL DB table using PHP

I have a text.xml file that has a timestamp (under MeanPublic) in which is ISO8601 format, i.e. YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS

I can read the file in PHP, I can echo that ISO8601 date, however, if I insert it into MySQL it just logs 0000-00-00 00:00:00. I've tried stripping the "T" out of the date but doesnt work.

Ive tried setting the database table field in vchar, char, int, date, datetime, and time, just nothing. However, if I put in the insert a manual date/time it inserts ok.

It's crucial that it logs as date/time because I need to run date/time queries later on these values

Here's the code

```
if( ! $xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml') ) 
    { 
        echo 'unable to load XML file'; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        foreach( $xml as $MeanPublic ) 
        {
        $key = split(":", $MeanPublic->Key);
        $meanvalue = $MeanPublic->Mean;
        $FTSvalue = str_replace('T', ' ', $MeanPublic->Timestamp);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (totwhout, wbstamp) VALUES ($meanvalue, $FTSvalue)");
       }
```

Comment: Can you show us what your $FTSValue looks like?  Even better, what do you get if you echo your entire query string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've probably already checked this, but are you putting single quotes around the timestamp value when constructing the query?  Judging from your posted code, it doesn't look like you are -- MySQL expects the TIMESTAMP values to be passed like strings in that regard.

Comment: Hi, sorry but how would that look? what you see in the code is what im using.

Comment: Your query string would be constructed like so:

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (totwhout, wbstamp) VALUES ($meanvalue, '$FTSvalue')");

Comment: Don't believe it! How did I not spot that is anyone's guess. Thank you so much

Comment: No worries -- it happens to the best of us ;)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this problem was not caused by DATE/TIME format. You should surround strings with quotation in SQL.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (totwhout, wbstamp) VALUES ('$meanvalue', '$FTSvalue')");
```